# Disable Select all option in jQuery multiple select plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using below jQuery plugin, it works fine.

I want to know how to hide "Select all" option if drop-down has no item(s).

And is there any way we can disable multiple select dropdown?

[Jquery muliple select plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Elements-Multiple-Select.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When no option in list Hiding select All:**

```js
      $(function() { 
            $("#select3").multipleSelect({
                isopen: true,
                multipleWidth: 55
            });
          //  selectAll 
            console.log(!$('#select3 option').length);
            if(!$('#select3 option').length){
                      $('input[name="selectAll"]').parent().hide();
            }

            
        });
```

```html
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Elements-Multiple-Select/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Elements-Multiple-Select/jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
<select id="select3" class="demo" style="width:200px;">

</select>
```

**Hiding multiple select dropdown:**

```js
      $(function() { 
            $("#select3").multipleSelect({
                isopen: true,
                multipleWidth: 55
            });
            $(".ms-choice").hide();
        });
```

```html
   <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Elements-Multiple-Select/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Elements-Multiple-Select/jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
<select id="select3" class="demo" style="width:200px;">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am searching for plugin's own callback function, but still voting you for your efforts..